# Reusable Custom Control with Properties

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I have built a Custom Control Class that makes it much easier to build a side bar element in my html.

The problem I am running into is that when I set the "Text" property, the last time I set it gets used for every instance of the control on my page.  This is my first time doing this, so I'm assuming I'm missing something basic.

```
Namespace CustomControl
Public Class SideBarElement : Inherits Literal

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create Copyright Label
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        MyBase.Text = RenderHTML()
        MyBase.CreateChildControls()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Set all copyright information.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function RenderHTML() As String
        Dim val As String


        val = "<div class=""side-bar-container"">" & _
                  "<div class=""side-bar-top"">" & _
                  "</div>" & _
                 " <div class=""side-bar-content"">" & _
                 _Text & _
                  "</div>" & _
                  "<div class=""side-bar-bottom"">" & _
                  "</div>" & _
              "</div>"

        Return val
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create Text Property
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Shared _Text As String = String.Empty
    Public Shadows Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

End Namespace

Using this control is supposed to look like this.

```
<sidebar:SideBarElement ID="SideBarElement1" runat="server">
 Bla Bla</br>My Fun Content.</sidebar:SideBarElement>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Text and _Text properties solved the problem.  The literal control already has those properties built in, so I don't need to override them.

```
Namespace CustomControl
Public Class SideBarElement : Inherits Literal

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create Copyright Label
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
        MyBase.Text = "<div class=""side-bar-container"">" & _
                            "<div class=""side-bar-top""></div>" & _
                            "<div class=""side-bar-content"">" & _
                                Text & _
                            "</div>" & _
                      "</div>"
        MyBase.CreateChildControls()
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: Also, removing the "Shared" from the properties would have solved it just as well.